# Trouble while extending a disk partition on Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, file-management, disk-space

I have an unallocated space, so I tried to extend my C:\ drive however I couldn't do the process "extend volume" option is disabled, you can see the image below,

[image: My disk management window]

Comment: Because there is a Recovery partition in between C drive and unallocated section.

Comment: yeah, how to deal with this case. @Biswapriyo

Comment: No need to delete, use a partition software boot disk to merge the 2 partitions C: and unallocated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't extend C partition. How to make unallocated space "adjacent"](https://superuser.com/questions/1080603/cant-extend-c-partition-how-to-make-unallocated-space-adjacent)