# Extend unallocated space to my `C:` drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I am using a machine with Windows 10.

After shrinking the size of the partition `D:` using `Disk Management`, I got 215.78GB Unallocated.

[image]

Now, I want to Extend the Volume of the partition `C:` with the Unallocated space and for that, I right-clicked and can't press the "Extend Volume..." as the button is inactive.

[image]

In order to extend my C: partition, I have tried what [this answer suggests](https://superuser.com/a/1080609/717009)

> - create a new partition in the free space
> - move everything from D to there (turn of the page file first, and activate it again at the end
>   of the whole operation!)
> - delete D and relabel the new partition to D
> - After that, you can expand C into the free space (and also the new partition, if you want it to be as large as D originally was).

But still didn't solve my problem. Now my disk looks like the following

[image]

How do I proceed in order to allocate the unallocated space to my `C:` drive?

It seems that the partitions Healthy are the one's coming in between me and my solution as, [as it points out here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771473(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> You can add more space to existing primary partitions and logical
> drives by extending them into adjacent unallocated space on the same
> disk. To extend a basic volume, it must be raw or formatted with the
> NTFS file system. You can extend a logical drive within contiguous
> free space in the extended partition that contains it.

And those two may be the adjacent to the `C:` drive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 1st partition doesn't matter. It's only the 3rd partition which sits "between" C: and the empty space.

Use something like GParted Live CD to move the whole partition all the way to the right. This will result in empty space immediately next to C: and you'll be able to use "Expand".

(GParted can also resize NTFS partitions itself, but I probably wouldn't recommend doing so for the system partition.)

Comment: In fact, I would say to move that partition to the end of the drive, which allows to remove the D: partition or change it's size later on. This works best if the D: partition is empty, in which case it's better to remove it.