# How can I move space from drive C to drives farther away?

Tags: windows-10, disk-management

I have drive C, D, and E.

My E is full and my C has a lot of empty space.

However, no matter how much I shrink C, the unallocated space won't be available to E.

The unallocated space remains in between C and D.

How can I move empty space from drive C, to drives other than D?

Comment: Use Third party partitioning software

Comment: And make a backup

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1256334/how-to-extend-c-drive-to-claim-unallocated-space?rq=1) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1614019/extend-unallocated-space-to-my-c-drive?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend C: drive to claim unallocated space?](https://superuser.com/questions/1256334/how-to-extend-c-drive-to-claim-unallocated-space)

Answer (score 3):

I understand that your disk partitions look like this :

```
C | unallocated space | D | E
```

If you wish to increase the size of E, you need to move
the unallocated space to after it.

As unallocated space cannot be moved, you need to move the partitions.
You need to move D on top of the unallocated space, which will then
look like this :

```
C | D | unallocated space | E
```

Then repeat the exercise for E, so it looks like :

```
C | D | E | unallocated space
```

Only then you will be able to resize E.

As Windows has no tools for moving partitions, you will need to use
a third-party partition editor. An example is
[AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html)
or its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-partition-assistant/).

Warning : Partition editing is dangerous, as any mistake can destroy
your data. Ensure that you have good backups for your data,
and I also recommend an image backup of the entire disk.
Get help from a knowledgeable person if you don't feel safe with this.