# Is it possible to extent my C: drive in this case?

Tags: disk-management

How to move the recovery parition and D: drive to make it possibile to unallocated space to extent to C:. the unallocated space will be e: after deleting it.

My case :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't extend C partition. How to make unallocated space "adjacent"](https://superuser.com/questions/1080603/cant-extend-c-partition-how-to-make-unallocated-space-adjacent)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deleting E will replace it by unallocated space that needs to be "moved"
after C to extend it.

You can't move Unallocated space, so you need to move D *and* the
recovery partition down over this space. This will in effect move the
unallocated space to after C.

As Windows has no tools for moving partitions, you will need to use
a third-party partition editor.

Warning : Partition editing is dangerous, as any mistake can destroy
your data. Ensure that you have good backups for your data,
and I also recommend an image backup of the entire disk.

An example third-party product is
[AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Freeware](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html)
or its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-partition-assistant/).
I also recommend
[AOMEI Backupper Free](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
and its
[Create Bootable Disc Based on Windows PE or Linux](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html),
in case a problem occurs, to be able to restore the disk.

Comment: And make absolutely sure the boot, C:, recovery and D: partition remain in the same order with no extra partitions in between. If the ordering changes the system will be unbootable or (worse) will partially boot and Windows will try to repair itself which will really screw up things beyond repair. BACKUP before you attempt any of this.