# How to extend windows partitions, and how to solve C: partition extension issue

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, storage, disk-space

The C: drive needs more storage space on my system drive.
When I take some space from D: drive, the space out is a free space,
the space needed is unallocated space to merge it into C: drive.
how can I solve this?

[image]

**Must be unallocated to merge it into the C: drive.**
[image]

**Can't merge it as free space**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Go to this site [easeus](https://easeus.com/)

**partition manager > partition master > partition master free**

[image]

**install the program and then open it**

Move the D: drive ahead so that its free space becomes
unallocated and can be merged with the C: drive.

[image]

finally apply changes and go to Expanding the space.

Comment: Did you intend to make this community wiki? We don't have a problem with people answering their own questions, though this question  is vaguely similar. https://superuser.com/questions/1080603/cant-extend-c-partition-how-to-make-unallocated-space-adjacent?rq=1